# adauth 2.0.0 errors with Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm currently testing an upgrade to Rails 3.1 for my app and as part of that my adauth gem was upgraded to 2.0.0 (from 1.2.1)

I followed the config changes mentioned in the adauth migration wiki. Specifically, my user model (called `Analyst`), now has this:

```
include Adauth::Rails::ModelBridge
```

and it has the new `AdauthMappings` and `AdauthSearchField` mappings defined, etc.

The problem I'm having is with this line in my `sessions_controller#create`:

```
analyst = Analyst.return_and_create_with_adauth(ldap_user)
```

which craps out with:

```
Following are details of the error: 
Message:undefined method `return_and_create_with_adauth' for #<Class:0x0000000cc41dd0>

Stack Trace: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/base.rb:1099:in `method_missing' 
/apps/automatix/trunk/automatix/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:13:in `create' 
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.12/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action' 
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.12/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action' 
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.12/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
```

Has anyone encountered this?

Of course, I don't *have* to migrate to 2.0.0 and downgrading to 1.2.1 works just fine.. but this is just out of curiosity.

Thanks

P.S. I tried to tag this with `adauth`, hoping to keep it more focused but apparently that tag doesn't exist and I can't create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, after inspecting the code there was a slight change between 1.2.1 and 2.0.X.

You need to change the method name from return_and_create_with_adauth to return_and_create_from_adauth.  The correction would be:

```
analyst = Analyst.return_and_create_from_adauth(ldap_user)
```

Here's a link to the new model:

https://github.com/Arcath/Adauth/blob/master/lib/adauth/rails/model_bridge.rb